# How can I use PC-Lint Plus's -esym with multiple message numbers?

Tags: c, pc-lint

I want to suppress warnings arising from including code with unused functions (I cannot change this code but need to use parts of it). I know that I could do this with several `-esym` statements each but I have a number of these to suppress and I think it will be clearer if they can be written as a single statement each. Is there a way to do this?

The PC-Lint Plus manual contains the following prototype for the `-esym` option:

> `-esym(# [# ...], Symbol [,Symbol ...])` inhibits the message #s parameterized by *Symbol*

This looks to me like the correct format would be:

```
-esym(765 759 714, ModuleName_*)
```

However, after adding this to my `.lnt` file I get the following error when linting:

> LintFile.lnt(156): Error 72: Bad option '-esym(765 759 714, ModuleName_*)'

Putting commas between the message numbers (which doesn't seem to be what the manual specifies) does not result in an Error 72 but also does not suppress the messages. My PC-Lint version is:

> PC-lint for C/C++ (NT) Vers. 9.00L, Copyright Gimpel Software 1985-2014

Comment: Probably not helping you right now, but the upcoming the C standard has a way to mark such functions with `[[maybe_unused]] int func (void)`. Many compilers and static analysers have yet to implement this though.